# Javascript closure behavior is strange at runtime

Tags: javascript

Consider this code:

```
function f1(p) {
    function f2() {
        console.log(p); //Output: 10
    }
    f2();
}

f1(10);
```

This code output is 10. But if I change it as code below:

```
function f1(p) {
    function f2() {
        debugger;
    }
    f2();
}

f1(10);
```

While I'm debugging the code in console, if i try to read p, i get:

```
ReferenceError: p is not defined
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not looking to make it work. When the console is stopped at debugger line, if You try to read p in console you will get reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is accessible in `f2` but because you don't use `p`, it seems `p` is removed by interpreter/compiler for performance issue after `f1` declaration and parse completed.

Comment: @MohammadZargarani If an edit is solely to correct 1 typo, don't suggest an edit where you replace some other words with synonyms (don't with do not for example), but instead leave a comment.

Comment: @Sumurai8 thank you for your concern but I don't think that correcting others concerns you! have a great day :)

Comment: @MohammadZargarani Because you suggested an edit, and I came across it in the review queue, I felt I needed to explain that. Usually those edits are simply rejected as 'too minor' anyway.

Comment: @Omid +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the host doesn't put all possible variables in the closure just because you may try to access them in the debugger. Rather, if `p` is not accessed in the inner function, it doesn't get into the closure and is not accessible.